# How to sync Google Calendar with Radicale, 2 way?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, radicale

I have my own calendar that works with Radicale server, i want to sync my calendar with my google calendar, if i create an event in my calendar i want to see it in my google calendar and if i edit that event in google calendar i want to see the change in my calendar.

I know that using the google calendar api i can set event from my calendar, but can't do it from google to my calendar.

I'm using this client to connect with radicale: https://github.com/gaye/dav

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Would like to know this answer